# Add special-character after every nth character in string

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am trying to find an elegant and correct way to convert my string e.g '50221' to '05.02.21'

The problem is, that some dates are like "060521" and some are like the above one.

I already tried to use regex for this but I wasnt successfull, also I tried:

```py
line = '050221'
n = 2
print([line[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(line), n)])
```

Currently I am only able to split them in a list, but I could imagine that there is a shorter and easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(\d{1,2})(\d{2})(\d{2})
```

You can use this and substitute by `\1:\2:\3`

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hch78C/1/

You can see the code too.

https://regex101.com/r/hch78C/1/codegen?language=python

Comment: can you pls show me an example, how I would write it in code? If I do ```>>> s = re.sub(r'(\d{1,2})(\d{2})(\d{2})', '\1:\2:\:3', s)
>>> print(s)
☺:☻:♥
```
I get some weird smileys :D

Answer (score 0):

Use `zfill` to convert the string to a common format, then use regex and `join` to insert the special characters.

```
import re
line = ('050221').zfill(6)
'.'.join(re.findall(r'.{1,2}', line))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use regex you can do it this way

```
from textwrap import wrap

line = '50221'.zfill(6)
line = wrap(line, 2)
line = ".".join(line)
```

more compactly

```
from textwrap import wrap

line = '50221'
line = ".".join(wrap(line.zfill(6), 2))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer Marco. In my investigation I already saw some methods with zfill,but I was not very satisfied with it. Have a nice day :)